# cannot connect to hbase instance

Tags: apache, hbase

I have followed the installation guide on the hbase website but to no avail have failed.  I get this error when I try to run the hbase shell command.  I have checked the directory and I do indeed have this file hbase-config.sh

```
hbase: 79: /home/test/HBase/hbase-0.98.13-hadoop2/bin/hbase-config.sh: [[: not found
hbase: 88: /home/test/HBase/hbase-0.98.13-hadoop2/bin/hbase-config.sh: [[: not found
hbase: 175: hbase: [[: not found
hbase: 197: hbase: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: whats the command you ran? Are you doing it on a mac or ubuntu?

Comment: @AnilGupta I ran sh hbase shell and I am doing it on ubuntu

Comment: You just need to run "hbase shell"

Comment: I tried that but get -sh: 7: hbase: not found

Comment: That basically means hbase command is not in your path. You have an incorrect setup. Google installing hbase on ubuntu and try to follow steps.